# Prove $W=Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}\iff \det(v_1,...,v_n)\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. I want to prove that $$W=Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}\iff \det(v_1,...,v_n)\neq 0.$$
Set $$V=\begin{pmatrix}v_1&\cdots& v_n\end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad \alpha =\begin{pmatrix}\alpha _1\\\vdots\\\alpha _n \end{pmatrix}$$

I know that $$V\alpha =0\implies \alpha =0,$$
and thus $V$ is injective (and thus bijective). So my problem is equivalent to prove that $V$ is invertible $\iff \det (V)\neq 0$. It's a result that I indeed always use, but I don't see how to prove it. I know that if $A$ is invertible, that it's inverse is of the form $\frac{B}{\det (A)} $ for some matrix $B$, and thus $\det(A)\neq 0$.

**Q1)** Can I say that ? I have the impression that I cheat a bit.

**Q2)** How can I prove that if $\det(A)\neq 0$, then $A$ is invertible ?

**Q3)** Maybe there is an other proof than using this Laplace formula of the inverse ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\det ... \neq 0$ ?

Comment: yeah Q2 does it, so a typo in title.

Comment: edited. Thank you.

Comment: Well first of all, you are abusing $V$ for both the vector space and the matrix, which is confusing.

Comment: OK, right. Anyhow, I would use the comatrix formula if I were you : $A . Com(A)^T = \det(A) . In$. Thus if the det is zero, you have vectors of the kernel, and if it is not, you have the inverse.

Comment: @G.Fougeron: If $A$ has rank $n-2$, then $Com(A)=0$, so how can you have the vectors of the kernel ?

Comment: The comatrice formula work to prove that $\det(A)\neq 0$ implies that $A$ is invertible only. For the converse, if $A$ is invertible, then there is $B$ s.t. $AB=I$, and thus $\det(A)\det(B)=1$. Therefore $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: @use859610 You are right, indeed, my mistake.